# Why I am not able to login on otter.ai using mechanize

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, automation, mechanize

Whenever I try parsing the username and password the script gets executed successfully but when I try to get all the links after successful login(on the dashboard) I still only get the links on the login page not on the dashboard.

I have already tried using selenium but I am always getting No Such element exception.

```
import mechanize
import urllib3
import http.cookiejar as cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]
br.open("https://otter.ai/login")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['email'] = 'username was here'
br.form['password'] = 'password here'

link = br.geturl()
links = br.open('link').read()
```

I want to get a list of all the links available on the dashboard page.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this Otter.ai website? You want to get the list of all links before login or after login? Looks like, after login, the website redirects to an Angular app.

Comment: I have some hundred of files that I want to download. After Login. So is there any way to get the links out even if it redirects to Angular app.